# Trying to understand libstdc++'s implementation of std::multiset

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, libstdc++, multiset

I was trying to peek into libstdc++'s implementation of `std::multiset` (just because I was curious) and I found this line https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/stl_multiset.h#L118, and didn't know what to make of it.  The way I understand it,  the [`_Rb_tree` class](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/stl_tree.h#L444) is a single element tree, how does that line turn that into a multiset?

The way I understand it, that line is just adapting the allocator for another type.  Or am I misunderstanding this terribly?

---

This is the linked code

```
private:
  /// This turns a red-black tree into a [multi]set.
  typedef typename __gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<_Alloc>::template
rebind<_Key>::other _Key_alloc_type;

  typedef _Rb_tree<key_type, value_type, _Identity<value_type>,
           key_compare, _Key_alloc_type> _Rep_type;
  /// The actual tree structure.
  _Rep_type _M_t;
```

Comment: Can you include the code you're questioning in your question instead of using a link?

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm done

Answer (score 2):

`_Rb_tree` doesn't decide whether duplicate values are allowed; it doesn't even know whether it has just a value or a separate key and value (it derives a key from the `pair` when used as a `map`).  The comment is merely indicating that template arguments are being chosen which make `_Rb_tree` useful as a set or multiset.  Comments earlier in the file point out that

> The private tree data is declared exactly the same way for set and
>   multiset; the distinction is made entirely in how the tree functions are
>   called (*_unique versus *_equal, same as the standard).

Comment: But the data structure has to support some sort of storage for duplicate values right?  Could you point me to where that is?

Comment: An `_Rb_tree` has many nodes in any case; as the comment says, it provides functions named ...`_unique` and ...`_equal`, so the policy is up to the client (`set` or `multiset` respectively).

Comment: @Curious The tree doesn't necessarily need to do anything special at all. It simply supports an insertion operation given a certain key, which it basically does by finding the correct spot for the key and then performing an insert there. If there happen to be identicals, that does not matter. The only way uniqueness will matter is if the tree balancing algorithm assumes that if `!(x<y)`, then `y < x`. If your balancing algorithm doesn't assume that then why does the lowest level tree have to care? Uniqueness can be implemented on top of that by doing a check on insertion.

Comment: @NirFriedman I am looking to find out what the data structure used for the many nodes is.  Is it a linked list? is it a vector?  That sort of stuff.  I can't for some reason find that piece of code...

Comment: It is, well, a red-black tree.  The [parent and 2 child pointers](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/stl_tree.h#L107) are in `_Rb_tree_node_base` for code size reasons.